# elasticsearch install plugins encounter "remote host terminated the handshake"

Tags: elasticsearch

1. run elastic search images in mac OS

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch-7.8 -p 9200:9200 -p 9308:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.8.0
```

2. install ik plugins in elastic search

```
./bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip`
```

3. I have encountered the followed issue

```
/bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
-> Installing https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
-> Downloading https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
-> Failed installing https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
-> Rolling back https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
-> Rolled back https://github.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/releases/download/v7.8.0/elasticsearch-analysis-ik-7.8.0.zip
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1661)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1470)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1370)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:171)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1595)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1523)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.downloadZip(InstallPluginCommand.java:448)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.download(InstallPluginCommand.java:329)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:251)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.InstallPluginCommand.execute(InstallPluginCommand.java:224)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.MultiCommand.execute(MultiCommand.java:91)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginCli.main(PluginCli.java:47)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:167)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1462)
```

4. The network is OK, I can download readme file in docker images

```
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/medcl/elasticsearch-analysis-ik/master/README.md
```

Comment: Did you checked your SSL config? [like](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-docker/issues/124)